# Local Host/Local Network Https

Tags: http, security, https, localhost, webcam

I am currently pursuing MSc in Applied Cyber Security from the Queen’s University Belfast. I am doing the dissertation on the topic Simple SSL.

In this project, we are investigating how to use SSL encryption for local network devices that have web interfaces, such as IP cameras. Current browsers treat self-signed certificates as a security threat and as far as we can identify there is no trusted method for using SSL in this context.

I, under the supervision of my dissertation supervisor Dr John Bustard, have achieved the solution.

I want to ask that, do we really need https on localhost/local network or http is fine?

Comment: There is a difference between "localhost" and "local network". You certainly should prefer encrypted traffic in a network, but it makes absolutely no sense inside a loopback interface.

Comment: Beside that I fail to understand the issue you try to solve. Certainly you can use self signed certificates for such purpose. All you need to do is import the signing certificates into the clients on that local network. Or you use normal certificates, for example Let's encrypt certificates in combination with fully qualified domain names, that works perfectly also in local networks.

Comment: Let's Encrypt does not allow you to use their certificates on a local host or local network. To use them you need to have a registered domain name.

Comment: Which is _exactly_ what I wrote above. You cannot use _unqualified_ domain names, true. That has nothing do to with Let's encrypt, but with how validation works. But you very well can use their certificate (any validable certificate, actually) in a local network, _if you are using qualified domain names_. That is what I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ask that, do we really need https on localhost/local network or http is fine?

HTTPS on localhost (127.x.x.x) is a waste of resources, since you're encrypting network traffic that doesn't pass over an actual network.

HTTPS on the local network is quite valuable in the real world, since the reality is that you can't trust your local network much more than you can trust the internet. If you have valuable data, there's always a way to intercept the traffic.

None of the public Certification Authorities will issue a certificate for a local network. This is typically implemented by creating a CA on the local network and installing the CA's certificate as a trusted root on the workstations and devices.

The catch is that some inexpensive devices like cameras typically do not allow the end user to install a trusted root certificate, which means that they can not implement SSL on the local network using the new cert.

Cameras usually ship with a certificate from the manufacturer, however whether or not it's trusted (or should be trusted) is a different issue. It may be self-signed by the manufacturer, or from an untrusted or unknown CA

TL/DR: Most devices on a local network can use certificates issued by the local CA. Inexpensive network devices that the user can't/doesn't know how to update are a security issue.

Comment: You can create certificates for domainnames, which point to local ip's.