# Does website running on local area network need https protection?

Tags: web, https, lan

I was asked today if a website running on a secured LAN, really needs https protection? I could not give a satisfactory answer more than that the traffic can be intercepted and read on http but not on https. Something similar has been also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52100875/7480460).

My question is could my response have been better? Are there more reasons to securing website running on LAN?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS Protocol will only protect MITM (Man In The Middle) sort of attacks.

The meaning is that the hacker need a way to communicate with the server.

In public websites HTTPS is important because ANYONE can talk with the server but if the website is running on a secured LAN the hacker will first need to hack his way to the LAN network in order to eavesdropping to the traffic of the website.

So - HTTPS on LAN running website is another layer of defense in case the hacker find his way into the LAN network, but for my opinion it's total waste of resources and time.

If the hacker found his way inside the network he can do a lot of things that HTTPS will be his last concern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Getting access to LAN may not be that hard. Consider a hypothetical situation where an employee is about to leave the company and on his/her last few days wishes to eavesdrop on the transactions occurring on "the" web site (that is not running on https)..perhaps to start own company afterwards or to sell it somewhere (the employee is talented and disgruntled). Is having a https protection still very costly and useless? If it is, then I guess you have already answered it. If not, then my question was .. what are driving reasons for protecting a website running on LAN?